# Should I register my entire source code base as text models in monaco-editor?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm working on a small cloud IDE for an in-house language using monaco editor as the code editor.

In order to make features like "Find All References" , which work across source files via uri's, work , is it the idea that I register all the source files as ITextModel's in the editor? Or is there some hook that when the ReferenceProvider tool item is clicked , will allow to load up a text model on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with the same problem until a few days ago, and the answer to me was for your question was **NO**. You do not register all your source code as ITextModel's. Not even VSCode does that.

I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/nmanumr/monaco-basic) repo a few days ago. The code was written 2 years ago and is obsolete, but none the less is still really helpful and with minor adjustments you can get it working in no time. The actual code spans multiple files and functions and it may not be practical to write it here, follow the link for the actual code. But perhaps this is what you're looking for `monaco.languages.registerReferenceProvider`;

Comment: Hi.  So I understand monaco.languages.registerReferenceProvider produces the locations for the current model, let's say uri://sourcefile1.   Now let's say this file imports a method from from another file uri://sourcefile2 and users does a "Find References" on that method, we know from our SymbolTable that the source location for that method is in uri://sourcefile2.   However, Monaco editor isn't aware of this file,  so either it needs to be registered with monaco as a model, or there is some hook that we can handle which will load the model.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Quite honestly, I'm still working on it this week. But my best guess is we use the result from the reference provider and add models dynamically at that time. I'll post a more elaborate answer here once I'm done with it. In the meantime, have you found the solution?

Comment: not yet.  I'm blocked on dev work for the moment to even enable find references for a single file.   If I hit it first, I will definitely update on here.